# how to aggregate a big data frame by sliding window along the rows

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a big data frame like this:

```
df = read.table(text="POS   m1  m2  m3  m4  m5  m6  m7  m8
            16617   B   B   H   H   H   H   B   H
            16625   B   B   H   H   H   H   B   H
            16666   B   B   H   H   H   B   B   H
            16828   B   B   H   H   H   B   B   A
            19429   B   B   H   A   B   B   B   A
            66665   B   A   H   A   B   B   B   A
            67144   B   A   H   A   B   B   B   A
            67238   B   A   H   A   B   B   B   H
            67772   B   A   H   A   H   B   B   H
            67881   B   A   H   A   H   B   B   H
            68128   B   A   H   A   H   B   B   H
            69120   A   A   B   H   H   B   B   H", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

The first column is used to sort the rows. The rest of columns have only three elements or values (A, B or H). I want to a sliding window (such as a size of five rows, with two rows as one step) to aggregate the data to one row from each sliding window, by taking the majority of elements from the sliding window. The expected result looks like this:

```
            POS m1  m2  m3  m4  m5  m6  m7  m8
            16617   B   B   H   H   H   B   B   H
            16666   B   B   H   A   B   B   B   A
            19429   B   A   H   A   B   B   B   A
            67144   B   A   H   A   H   B   B   H
            67772   B   A   H   A   H   B   B   H
```

I hope someone could help me with this question. Thanks.

Comment: Why is the last row of m1 A? If you take a sliding window of 5, the majority of elements are "B"

Comment: You are right. I have edited it. the last sliding window size is the last of four rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zoo::rollapply` to apply a function (here, a mode, taken from `collapse`) on a sliding window. The width is 5, and `partial = TRUE` to allow partial computation. You can use `by` to compute `FUN` every n rows:

> **by** calculate FUN at every by-th time point rather than every point.
> by is only used if width is length 1 and either a plain scalar or a
> list.

```r
library(zoo)
library(collapse)
rollapply(df[-1], FUN = fmode, width = 5, partial = TRUE, by = 2) |> 
  cbind(df[1])

#    m1 m2 m3 m4 m5 m6 m7 m8   POS
# 1   B  B  H  H  H  H  B  H 16617
# 2   B  B  H  H  H  B  B  H 16625
# 3   B  B  H  A  B  B  B  A 16666
# 4   B  A  H  A  B  B  B  A 16828
# 5   B  A  H  A  H  B  B  H 19429
# 6   B  A  H  A  H  B  B  H 66665
# 7   B  B  H  H  H  H  B  H 67144
# 8   B  B  H  H  H  B  B  H 67238
# 9   B  B  H  A  B  B  B  A 67772
# 10  B  A  H  A  B  B  B  A 67881
# 11  B  A  H  A  H  B  B  H 68128
# 12  B  A  H  A  H  B  B  H 69120
```

Comment: how to define the step size? in this case, the step size is two. I want to do the real data with sliding window size as 15, and step size as 5.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by step size? do you want the calculation to be done only once every 2 rows?

Comment: step size means how many rows skipped from the previous sliding window. In this case, The first window starts from row 1, the second sliding window starts from row 3. so the step size is 2.

Comment: You can use `by`, see edit

Answer (score 0):

You could grow `seq`uences of length `n` and steps `s` and `table` them like so:

```
n <- 5; s <- 2
t(sapply(seq.int(0L, dim(df)[1] - n + 1L , s), \(x, y) 
         sapply(df[x + y, -1], \(z) names(which.max(table(z)))), 1:n)) |>
  `rownames<-`(head(df$POS[seq_along(df$POS) %% 2 == 1], dim(df)[1]/s - 1))

#       m1  m2  m3  m4  m5  m6  m7  m8 
# 16617 "B" "B" "H" "H" "H" "B" "B" "H"
# 16666 "B" "B" "H" "A" "B" "B" "B" "A"
# 19429 "B" "A" "H" "A" "B" "B" "B" "A"
# 67144 "B" "A" "H" "A" "H" "B" "B" "H"
# 67772 "B" "A" "H" "A" "H" "B" "B" "H"
```

If you don't like the matrix, pipe it in `|> as.data.frame()`.

BTW, the outer `sapply` does this:

```
sapply(seq.int(0L, dim(df)[1] - n + 1L, s), `+`, 1:n)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    3    5    7    9
# [2,]    2    4    6    8   10
# [3,]    3    5    7    9   11
# [4,]    4    6    8   10   12
# [5,]    5    7    9   11   13
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(POS = c(16617L, 16625L, 16666L, 16828L, 19429L, 
66665L, 67144L, 67238L, 67772L, 67881L, 68128L, 69120L), m1 = c("B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A"), m2 = c("B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), m3 = c("H", 
"H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "B"), m4 = c("H", 
"H", "H", "H", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "H"), m5 = c("H", 
"H", "H", "H", "B", "B", "B", "B", "H", "H", "H", "H"), m6 = c("H", 
"H", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), m7 = c("B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), m8 = c("H", 
"H", "H", "A", "A", "A", "A", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Comment: This works for n<-5, s<-2. But if s <- 3, an error is shown as: Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent

Comment: @user3354212 See update, where this fails.

Comment: this code works well on my windows computer with R-4.1.2 but in a linux server which runs R-4.0.3 there is errors as Error: unexpected input in "t(sapply(seq.int(0L, dim(df)[1] - n + 1L , s), \".  the errors came from the two backslash signs in the code. Is there any solutions to fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Update your R or try `\`rownames<-\`(t(sapply(seq.int(0L, dim(df)[1] - n + 1L, s), function(x, 
    y) sapply(df[x + y, -1], function(z) names(which.max(table(z)))), 
    1:n)), head(df$POS[seq_along(df$POS)%%2 == 1], dim(df)[1]/s - 
    1))`